# How to set the value of textbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery

here is my code.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {              

   $('#cash_received').change(function () {
       $("#lname").val("mytest");
   }
   });
});
```

It does not set the value mytest in the Last Name text box.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you have a syntax error in your script and of course your event did not get registered because of that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#cash_received').change(function () {
        $("#lname").val("mytest");
    } //<-- Remove this
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JcyHH/)**

*Always look at your browser console for any errors, you can catch up all the syntax errors then and there itself*

Answer (score 3):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/VAcKN/

few things jsut as idea: (these are mere ideas yo) `:)` PSL nailed it anyways!

- How about `.keyPress`.
- End tag the `input` and chuck in `value=""`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#fname').change(function () {
        $("#lname").val("mytest");
    });
});
```